# BHO object won't load, probable registration trouble?

Tags: bho

I can't get Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer to load this BHO. Sure there's no COM objects that can be created, but Explorer can't know that until it loads the DLL and checks, but LoadLibrary isn't getting called.

The message box shows when I run regsvr32.

Windows Version = 8.1

Internet Epxlorer Version = 11

Enhance Protected Mode on or off doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <olectl.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

#define wstrlen wcslen

HINSTANCE me;

DWORD WINAPI M4(void *junk)
{    
    MessageBox(NULL, "Loaded", "bho", 0);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    wchar_t mainexe[1024];
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        me = hInstDll;
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(me);
        /* GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, mainexe, 1024); */
        /* len = wstrlen(mainexe); */

        HANDLE th = CreateThread(NULL, 32768, M4, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
return TRUE;
}

STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFIID rclsid,REFIID riid,LPVOID *ppv)
{
return CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE;
}

STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow()
{
return FALSE;
}

const char *CLSID_NAME = "CLSID\\{2D3E480A-0000-0000-0000-64756D796C6472}";
const char *CLSID_IPS32 = "CLSID\\{2D3E480A-0000-0000-0000-64756D796C6472}\\InProcServer32";
const char *BHO = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects\\{2D3E480A-0000-0000-0000-64756D796C6472}";
const wchar_t *name = L"Redacted BHO";
const char *apt = "Apartment";

STDAPI DllRegisterServer()
{
HKEY hk;
wchar_t dllpath[1024];

GetModuleFileNameW(me,dllpath,1024);

if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, CLSID_NAME, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hk, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return SELFREG_E_CLASS;
RegSetValueExW(hk, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE *)(name), (wstrlen(name) + 1) << 1);
RegCloseKey(hk);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, CLSID_IPS32, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hk, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return SELFREG_E_CLASS;
RegSetValueExW(hk, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE *)(dllpath), (wstrlen(dllpath) + 1) << 1);
RegSetValueEx(hk, "ThreadingModel", 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE *)(apt), 10);
RegCloseKey(hk);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, BHO, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hk, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return SELFREG_E_CLASS;
RegCloseKey(hk);
return S_OK;
}

STDAPI DllUnregisterServer()
{
RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, BHO);
RegDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, CLSID_IPS32);
RegDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, CLSID_NAME);
}
```

Comment: Do you see your BHO in Manage Add-ons window of IE?

Comment: Stupid question but was there a message "DllRegisterServer in YourBHO.dll succeeded" after you run regsvr32? Regsvr32 was run with admin right? Also did you check created registry keys and values with Registry Editor?

Comment: There is new registry key to add for IE11. What is your IE version?

Comment: Enhanced Protected Mode is on? What is the file path of your BHO?

Comment: IE Version = 11, obviously. I'm willing to bet it's the new key.

Comment: @Joshua Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Sorry haven't had time to test it yet. Probably this weekend.

Comment: You don't build and register a 32 bit BHO and then launch a 64 bits IE, don't you?

Comment: Nope. It's 64 bit BHO and 64 bit IE.

Answer (score 0):

For IE11 in enhanced protected mode (EPM), the registry must be updated with:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{your BHO CLSID}\Implemented
>   Categories\{59FB2056-D625-48D0-A944-1A85B5AB2640}

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. Good try though.